Getting error while embedding indic fonts in pdf using pdf-lib nodejs
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'xCoordinate')
Tried to download pdf after embedding indic fonts using pdf-lib.
Facing issues while writing indic fonts into existing pdf with custom font family using pdf-lib library in nodejs

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
